# Feathers js how to customize get service endpoint

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, sequelize.js, feathersjs

So I want to attach a url to my user requests which is in another service. How to customize get request?

```js
const { Service } = require('feathers-sequelize')

exports.Users = class Users extends Service {
  get(id, params) {
    // how to add custom data into to the get result?
    return super.get(id, params)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You retrieve the value from `super` and return a new object:

```js
const { Service } = require('feathers-sequelize')

exports.Users = class Users extends Service {
  async get(id, params) {
    // how to add custom data into to the get result?
    const data = await super.get(id, params)

    return {
      ...data,
      // when using raw: false:
      // ...data.toJSON(),
      message: 'New data here'
    }
  }
}
```